It says an error “The connection was not closed the connection's current state is open”. Is this ok an into statement into select statement?
 Try
        con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT CLIENT,SERVICE, SUBTOT FROM tblAppointment WHERE CLIENT='" & name & "'", con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            If MsgBox("Do you really want to add " + name + "?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

                cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblPayment (INVOICE, CUSNAME, SERVICE, PRICE)VALUES(@INVOICE,@CUSNAME,@SERVICE,@PRICE)", con)

                With cmd
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@INVOICE", lblInvoNum.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CUSNAME", dr.Item("CLIENT"))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SERVICE", dr.Item("SERVICE"))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRICE", dr.Item("SUBTOT"))
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                End With
                con.Close()
                txtSearch.Clear()
                loadCart()
            End If
        End If
        dr.Close()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        con.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
    End Try`

“The connection was not closed the connection's current state is open”. I dont know if it is ok to put insert into statement into select statement.

Your code is a bit of a mess. You have multiple con.Close calls in there for a start. Why? You have a Try block so anything that must be done whether an exception is thrown or not should be in a Finally block. If you're going to do things that way, you should have one and only one con.Close call there. The proper way to do it would be to not keep reusing the same objects or variables. You should be declaring your variables and creating your objects where you use them, with Using statements. That will guarantee that everything is cleaned up properly.

Also, how does it make sense to call dr.Read and then test dr.HasRows? Do you want to read data or not? It doesn;t look like it, so don't call dr.Read. If all you care about is whether there are records in the result set then just test dr.HasRows. Also, you should be closing that data reader if you want to execute another command over the same connection.

Where should I close the data reader? I just want the records.

"Where should I close the data reader?". Immediately after you finish using it. "I just want the records". You say that but you have no code to actually get the data from the records, so it seems like you're not telling us the truth. Either that or your code doesn't really make sense for what you want to do. If all you actually want is to know whether there are rows in the result set then that's what HasRows is for. Don't call Read unless you actually want to read those rows, in which case you need to actually get data from them.

If all you want to know is whether there are records that match specific criteria then don't use a data reader at all. Write SQL that returns a count of the rows or a Boolean indicating whether there are rows, then call ExecuteScalar to get that single value.

I have no idea what that last comment is supposed to mean. You've just posted code - unformatted and pretty much unreadable code - with no context or explanation whatsoever. No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Edit your question and provide ALL the relevant information there. That would mean formatting the relevant code and explaining what it is supposed to be doing.
